# Can I still use fly mode in 2.7?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

I used to use the mouse wheel in fly mode to move the view/camera smoothly backward and forward while controlling the speed at the same time.

I updated to Blender 2.70 and it seems that this is not working anymore.
Can I still use this navigation method in 2.70? How?

Comment: Since I migrated to 2.70 this has been annoying me and I couldn't find the answer to it easily. So I tried formulating a question as carefully as possible, hope that this would help people encountering the same issue. Having said that, walk mode is definitely worth a try.

Comment: Good to have the option, but I'm not sure why anyone would *want* to have the old fly mode back since it was slow and difficult to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can still use mouse wheel in fly mode.

It appears that since 2.70, [there is a new 'walk mode'](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.70/Game_Development#View_Navigation) which is the new default.
To restore fly mode, go to *user preferences > input*. Towards bottom left under View Navigation, choose Fly instead of Walk.

Note: In walk mode mouse wheel silently adjusts speed of walking.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use both fly and walk mode without toggling settings in your preferences constantly, it's still accessible in *3D view > Header > View > Navigation > Fly mode*:

[image]

Since that's kind of a pain to get to if you use it a lot, you can:

- Use the search menu (<kbd>Space</kbd> > `fly`)
- Create a custom shortcut by right clicking on the option in the menu and selecting *Add Shortcut*.

This way you can have both fly and walk mode within easy access.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble flying in Blender 2.76, but I found that changing the active camera's focal length (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>) or the general view angle (<kbd>N</kbd> Properties Panel) can actually shrink / explode the fly-mode dock (that box in the middle of the screen)... If the dock is reduced to a dot, the fly-mode viewport goes crazy because the cursor's relative displacement is jammed high; if the dock is expanded off-screen, basic fly-mode keys still function but rotation & any hope of 'flying' are dead because the dock is inescapable!

Started looking for bug reports on this, but now I think the real/virtual camera linkage might be for consistency sake. Eg. how could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> set the active camera to a view if it did not share that view's optical characteristics?

Something to be aware of anyway!